# How to get calculated a column from filtereed data set with google visualization

Tags: javascript, statistics, google-visualization

So, this is bending my mind, I'm hoping smarter brains than mine can point me in the right direction.  I'd appreciate any help.

I have a datatable like the one below:

```
value action     country region
-     -          -       -
4     sent       uk      eu
2     recieved   uk      eu
6     sent       fr      eu
2     recieved   fr      eu
...
```

and I'd like to get to a dataview like the below:

```
value country region
-     -       -
.5    uk      eu
.33   fr      eu
...
```

where the value column in table 2 reflects the retrieval rate for that country - a calculation of the value for recieved for a given country divided by the value for sent for that same country.

I think I need to

1. Create two dataviews, one containing sent values and the other received
2. Inner join the two tables with country and region columns as keys
3. Rename the two 'value' columns to 'Value Sent' and 'Value Received'
4. Use setColumn to create a column labelled 'Rate' that is a calculation of the two value columns.

Does that sound right? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: that sounds right to me, only other way would be to calculate before creating the data table